# Linux Terminal PS1

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, ps1, xfce

I am not sure if this is possible but I couldn't find the answer anywhere else or even people who have tried it but my current PS1 is this:

```
export PS1="\[\e[00;32m\]??\[\e[0m\]\[\e[00;37m\]\n\[\e[0m\]\[\e[01;31m\]\d\[\e[0m\]\[\e[00;37m\] \[\e[0m    \]\[\e[01;31m\]\T\[\e[0m\]\[\e[00;37m\]\n\[\e[0m\]\[\e[00;32m\]>\[\e[0m\]"
```

It is showing up and working upon opening the terminal however I am wondering if it was possible to clear the screen after a command finishes (with a prompt similar to windows cmd 'pause' command if possible) so that it isn't repeated or shown at the bottom of the window

I am running Manjaro XFCE if it makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
PS1='$(echo "(press enter to continue)" > /dev/tty ; read ; clear) $ '
```

**NOTE:** You need the redirect `> /dev/tty` because the standard output of the commands run by `PS1` goes nowhere.

Replace the ending `$` with whatever prompt you want to show.

I don't really think it is such a good idea. In the short time I've been testing that, it is so irritating!!!

I think you are way better just pressing `Ctrl+L` befor typing your command to clear the terminal.